# Using Google's flight search engine api to make api requests WITHOUT destination

Tags: json, google-qpx-express-api

I would like to create an Ios app (Swift 3.0 + Xcode 8) that uses Google's QPX Express API to request flight searches WITHOUT a specific destination or airport.

I want the user to input: departure airport/origin, budget and number of people travelling. When I run a test request from "qpxExpress.trips.search - QPX Express API v1", the request requires a destination. But when I use Google Flights (which I assume relies on the same API), the search engine gives you the possibility of choosing a continent or no destination at all.

Is it possible to make API requests without a specific destination using Google's QPX Express API?

Comment: I'm looking for the same answer, did you come to an answer elsewhere? Only thing I can think of is to do multiple requests of all possible countries but that seems extremely inefficient and expensive.

Comment: No :/ Yup, thought the same thing. Do you have en email? Would like to hear your thoughts on the approach and generally why you're interested in such a request :)

Answer (score 1):

On [qpx demo](https://qpx-express-demo.itasoftware.com/) you can try the api, unfortunatly the possiblility of looking for something else than an airport or city code is unavailable.

> Flight origins and destinations must be 3-character city/airport codes